# two node Elasticsearch cluster having data sync issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a 2 node Elasticsearch cluster with both as master eligible nodes. They both are formed a cluster and named as **node1 and **node2. Couple of weeks back we have upgraded the version of ES from 7.9 to 7.17.4. Now there was an issue reported that there is some data sync issue between the nodes.

When hitting elasticsearch url we are seeing different data for an index. so we tried to hit two node urls individually as below and we observed different data on each node.

curl http://node1:9200/vehicle/_search?q=***

curl http://node2:9200/vehicle/_search?q=***

I know that data on a cluster will get synced automatically on elasticsearch but I think this is not happening in my case. Could you please let me know why this is happening ? is there anything that I can forcefully sync data between nodes.
What could be the reason to get different data on the nodes ? what should I check why there is a different data getting populated ?

Here are the curl queries and their results on two nodes. Node 2 has an additional object along with the first object with a small difference in the last line.

**curl http://node1:9200/vehicle/_search?q=XYZ**

```
    {
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 7.8380795,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "vehicle_inventory",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "109802",
        "_score": 7.8380795,
        "_source": {
          "abs": "Yes",
          "addressLine1": "965 ALDRIN DR",
          "addressLine2": " ",
          "aeroCabExtenders": "Yes",
          "aeroRoof": " ",
          "aeroSideFairings": "Yes",
          "airConditioning": "Yes",
          "areaName": " ",
          "areaNumber": "0617",
          "bodyMake": "NULL",
          "bodySerialNumber": "NULL",
          "bodyFloorType": "",
          "bodyRoofType": "",
          "brakeType": "NULL",
          "cabStyle": "Conventional",
          "category": "TRACTOR",
          "chassisBumper": "AERO",
          "chassisMakeCode": "FTL",
          "cdlRequired": "Yes",
          "city": "Eagan",
          "color": "White",
          "modified_color": "WHITE",
          "compared": false,
          "saved": false,
          "country": "US",
          "countryExt": "United States",
          "collisionWarning": "No",
          "collisionWarningModel": "",
          "customerNumber": "RENTAL",
          "description": "AVAILABLE JANUARY 2022",
          "displayDeliveryCal": "Y",
          "districtName": " ",
          "driverSeatType": "AIR",
          "emailAddress": "E-MAIL.GENERAL.LOCATION@XXXXXX",
          "engineBrake": "Yes",
          "engineMake": "Detroit",
          "engineModel4": "DD15AT",
          "engineHours": 0,
          "faxNumber": "06516860476",
          "featuredListing": "Y",
          "frontAxleCapacity": "13300",
          "frontWheelType": "",
          "fuelType": "DIESEL",
          "grossVehicleWeight": 80000,
          "height": "NULL",
          "horsepower": 455,
          "image": "/usedtrucks/image/109802/1",
          "interiorLevel": "PREMIUM",
          "individualPageUrl": "",
          "liftGate": "NULL",
          "liftGateCapacity": "0",
          "liftGateModel": " ",
          "loadLength": "NULL",
          "make": "Freightliner",
          "managersSpecial": "false",
          "managerSpecialDiscountRetail": "0",
          "managerSpecialDiscountWholeSale": "0",
          "mileage": "701,830 miles",
          "model": "Cascadia 12564ST",
          "newListing": "false",
          "numberOfBunks": "2",
          "numberOfDriveAxles": "2",
          "numberOfTanks": "Dual",
          "numericHeight": "",
          "numericLoadLength": -1,
          "numericWidth": "",
          "offLease": "N",
          "originalWholeSalePrice": "64,500",
          "originalRetailPrice": "64,500",
          "phoneNumber": "1-866-309-1962",
          "promotionVehicle": "true",
          "rearAxleCapacity": "40000",
          "rearAxleMake": "Detroit",
          "rearDoor": "NULL",
          "rearRatio": "2.53",
          "rearWheelType": "",
          "reeferStandby": "",
          "refrigerationHours": "",
          "refrigerationMake": "NULL",
          "refrigerationModel": "NULL",
          "retailPrice": "54,500",
          "salePutUpDate": "2021-12-17 00:00:00",
          "sideConstruction": "NULL",
          "sideDoor": "NULL",
          "sleeperSize": "72",
          "sleeperType": "Raised Roof",
          "slidingFifthWheel": "Yes",
          "state": "MN",
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "statusComments": " ",
          "sale_reason_desc": "AVAILABLE JANUARY 2022",
          "saleType": " ",
          "size": "",
          "suspension": "Air",
          "tareWeight": "18795",
          "thumbnail": "usedtrucks/image/109802t/1",
          "tireSize": "11R22.5",
          "tireType": "S/WAY",
          "totalFuelCapacity": "220",
          "transmissionMake": "Detroit",
          "transmissionModel": "12DA1550",
          "transmissionSpeed": "12",
          "transmissionType": "Automatic",
          "type": "Sleeper Tractor",
          "unitNumber": "109802",
          "use": "RENTAL",
          "vin": "3AKJGLD53FSGJ8668",
          "wheelBase": "228\"",
          "wheelType": "Aluminum",
          "wholesalePrice": "59,500",
          "width": "NULL",
          "year": 2015,
          "zip": "55121",
          "numeric_mileage": 701830,
          "numeric_retail_price": 54500,
          "numeric_wholesale_price": 59500,
          "dLatitude": 44.944400787353516,
          "dLongitude": -93.09329986572266,
          "bodyModel": null,
          "promotionAmount": "10,000",
          "salePrice": 0,
          "location": "016510",
          "jpegImage": "/usedtrucks/JpgServlet/109802_1.jpg",
          "translatedCategory": "Heavy Duty Tractors",
          "originalCategory": "Heavy Duty Tractors",
          "monFriHours": "M-F 8:00 am to 8:00 pm ET",
          "satHours": "Sat 9:00 am to 3:00 pm ET",
          "mobileSitePhone": "1-800-485-9671",
          "salePutUpDatesort": "2021-12-17",
          "stringyear": "2015",
          "range_grossVehicleWeight": null,
          "range_loadLength": null,
          "range_horsepower": "401 and more",
          "range_cabType": "Raised Roof",
          "range_retailCenter": null,
          "viewCount": "222ST15",
          "advertTerm": "Level 1",
          "numeric_Height": 0,
          "numeric_totalFuelCapacity": 0,
          "numeric_Width": 0,
          "promotionList": [
            {
              "name": "Save on Select Sleeper Tractors",
              "description": "Save on Select Sleeper Tractors",
              "amount": 10000,
              "amountDisplayRetail": "10,000",
              "amountDisplayWholeSale": "10,000",
              "type": "DISCOUNT",
              "rule": "viewCount != null and viewCount.equalsIgnoreCase('222ST15') and (year <= 2014 or numeric_mileage >= 700)"
            }
          ],
          "imageMaxInstance": 10,
          "defaultImageBeanList": null,
          "translationsMap": {
            "cdlRequired": "Yes",
            "countryExt": "United States",
            "advertTerm": "Level 1",
            "color": "White",
            "range_horsepower": "401 and more",
            "range_cabType": "Raised Roof",
            "model": "Cascadia 12564ST",
            "category": "Heavy Duty Tractors",
            "type": "Sleeper Tractor"
          },
          "vehicle_suggestions": {},
          "vehicle_locations": {
            "lon": "-93.0933",
            "lat": "44.9444"
          },
          "combo_filter": [
            {
              "filter_name": "range_horsepower",
              "filter_value": "401 and more"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "range_cabType",
              "filter_value": "Raised Roof"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "range_retailCenter",
              "filter_value": null
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "advertTerm",
              "filter_value": "Level 1"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "airConditioning",
              "filter_value": "Yes"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "category",
              "filter_value": "Heavy Duty Tractors"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "color",
              "filter_value": "White"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "engineMake",
              "filter_value": "Detroit"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "fuelType",
              "filter_value": "DIESEL"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "make",
              "filter_value": "Freightliner"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "model",
              "filter_value": "Cascadia 12564ST"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "newListing",
              "filter_value": "false"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "numberOfBunks",
              "filter_value": "2"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "numberOfDriveAxles",
              "filter_value": "2"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "state",
              "filter_value": "MN"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "transmissionMake",
              "filter_value": "Detroit"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "transmissionSpeed",
              "filter_value": "12"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "transmissionType",
              "filter_value": "Automatic"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "type",
              "filter_value": "Sleeper Tractor"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "collisionWarning",
              "filter_value": "No"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "canada",
              "filter_value": null
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "unitedStates",
              "filter_value": "MN"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "countryExt",
              "filter_value": "United States"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "promotionVehicle",
              "filter_value": "true"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "promotions",
              "filter_value": "Current Deals"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "promotions",
              "filter_value": "Save on Select Sleeper Tractors"
            }
          ],
          "slider_filter_integer": [
            {
              "filter_name": "numeric_mileage",
              "filter_value": 701830
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "year",
              "filter_value": 2015
            }
          ],
          "slider_filter_float": [
            {
              "filter_name": "numeric_retail_price",
              "filter_value": 54500
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "numeric_wholesale_price",
              "filter_value": 59500
            }
          ],
          "basic_filter": {},
          "rowNum": 2465,
          "displayManagerspecial": null,
          "displayPromotions": "true",
          "canada": null,
          "unitedStates": "MN",
          "mgrSpecialRetail": "false",
          "mgrSpecialWholesale": "false",
          "promotions": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**curl http://node2:9200/vehicle/_search?q=XYZ**

```
    {
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 7.8380795,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "vehicle_inventory",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "109802",
        "_score": 7.8380795,
        "_source": {
          "abs": "Yes",
          "addressLine1": "965 ALDRIN DR",
          "addressLine2": " ",
          "aeroCabExtenders": "Yes",
          "aeroRoof": " ",
          "aeroSideFairings": "Yes",
          "airConditioning": "Yes",
          "areaName": " ",
          "areaNumber": "0617",
          "bodyMake": "NULL",
          "bodySerialNumber": "NULL",
          "bodyFloorType": "",
          "bodyRoofType": "",
          "brakeType": "NULL",
          "cabStyle": "Conventional",
          "category": "TRACTOR",
          "chassisBumper": "AERO",
          "chassisMakeCode": "FTL",
          "cdlRequired": "Yes",
          "city": "Eagan",
          "color": "White",
          "modified_color": "WHITE",
          "compared": false,
          "saved": false,
          "country": "US",
          "countryExt": "United States",
          "collisionWarning": "No",
          "collisionWarningModel": "",
          "customerNumber": "RENTAL",
          "description": "AVAILABLE JANUARY 2022",
          "displayDeliveryCal": "Y",
          "districtName": " ",
          "driverSeatType": "AIR",
          "emailAddress": "E-MAIL.GENERAL.LOCATION@XXXXXX",
          "engineBrake": "Yes",
          "engineMake": "Detroit",
          "engineModel": "DD15AT",
          "engineHours": 0,
          "faxNumber": "06516860476",
          "featuredListing": "Y",
          "frontAxleCapacity": "13300",
          "frontWheelType": "",
          "fuelType": "DIESEL",
          "grossVehicleWeight": 80000,
          "height": "NULL",
          "horsepower": 455,
          "image": "/usedtrucks/image/109802/1",
          "interiorLevel": "PREMIUM",
          "individualPageUrl": "",
          "liftGate": "NULL",
          "liftGateCapacity": "0",
          "liftGateModel": " ",
          "loadLength": "NULL",
          "make": "Freightliner",
          "managersSpecial": "false",
          "managerSpecialDiscountRetail": "0",
          "managerSpecialDiscountWholeSale": "0",
          "mileage": "701,830 miles",
          "model": "Cascadia 12564ST",
          "newListing": "false",
          "numberOfBunks": "2",
          "numberOfDriveAxles": "2",
          "numberOfTanks": "Dual",
          "numericHeight": "",
          "numericLoadLength": -1,
          "numericWidth": "",
          "offLease": "N",
          "originalWholeSalePrice": "64,500",
          "originalRetailPrice": "64,500",
          "phoneNumber": "1-866-309-1962",
          "promotionVehicle": "true",
          "rearAxleCapacity": "40000",
          "rearAxleMake": "Detroit",
          "rearDoor": "NULL",
          "rearRatio": "2.53",
          "rearWheelType": "",
          "reeferStandby": "",
          "refrigerationHours": "",
          "refrigerationMake": "NULL",
          "refrigerationModel": "NULL",
          "retailPrice": "44,500",
          "salePutUpDate": "2021-12-17 00:00:00",
          "sideConstruction": "NULL",
          "sideDoor": "NULL",
          "sleeperSize": "72",
          "sleeperType": "Raised Roof",
          "slidingFifthWheel": "Yes",
          "state": "MN",
          "status": "ACTIVE",
          "statusComments": " ",
          "sale_reason_desc": "AVAILABLE JANUARY 2022",
          "saleType": " ",
          "size": "",
          "suspension": "Air",
          "tareWeight": "18795",
          "thumbnail": "usedtrucks/image/109802t/1",
          "tireSize": "11R22.5",
          "tireType": "S/WAY",
          "totalFuelCapacity": "220",
          "transmissionMake": "Detroit",
          "transmissionModel": "12DA1550",
          "transmissionSpeed": "12",
          "transmissionType": "Automatic",
          "type": "Sleeper Tractor",
          "unitNumber": "109802",
          "use": "RENTAL",
          "vin": "3AKJGLD53FSGJ8668",
          "wheelBase": "228\"",
          "wheelType": "Aluminum",
          "wholesalePrice": "59,500",
          "width": "NULL",
          "year": 2015,
          "zip": "55121",
          "numeric_mileage": 701830,
          "numeric_retail_price": 44500,
          "numeric_wholesale_price": 59500,
          "dLatitude": 44.944400787353516,
          "dLongitude": -93.09329986572266,
          "bodyModel": null,
          "promotionAmount": "10,000",
          "salePrice": 0,
          "location": "016510",
          "jpegImage": "/usedtrucks/JpgServlet/109802_1.jpg",
          "translatedCategory": "Heavy Duty Tractors",
          "originalCategory": "Heavy Duty Tractors",
          "monFriHours": "M-F 8:00 am to 8:00 pm ET",
          "satHours": "Sat 9:00 am to 3:00 pm ET",
          "mobileSitePhone": "1-800-485-9671",
          "salePutUpDatesort": "2021-12-17",
          "stringyear": "2015",
          "range_grossVehicleWeight": null,
          "range_loadLength": null,
          "range_horsepower": "401 and more",
          "range_cabType": "Raised Roof",
          "range_retailCenter": null,
          "viewCount": "222ST15",
          "advertTerm": "Level 1",
          "numeric_Height": 0,
          "numeric_totalFuelCapacity": 0,
          "numeric_Width": 0,
          "promotionList": [
            {
              "name": "Save on Select Sleeper Tractors",
              "description": "Save on Select Sleeper Tractors",
              "amount": 10000,
              "amountDisplayRetail": "10,000",
              "amountDisplayWholeSale": "10,000",
              "type": "DISCOUNT",
              "rule": "viewCount != null and viewCount.equalsIgnoreCase('222ST15') and (numeric_mileage < 700 or year > 2014)"
            },
            {
              "name": "Save on Select Sleeper Tractors. Save an additional $5,000 when financing with Premier Financing",
              "description": "Save on Select Sleeper Tractors. Save an additional $5,000 when financing with Premier Financing",
              "amount": 10000,
              "amountDisplayRetail": "10,000",
              "amountDisplayWholeSale": "10,000",
              "type": "DISCOUNT",
              "rule": "viewCount != null and viewCount.equalsIgnoreCase('222ST15') and (numeric_mileage >= 700 or year <= 2014) "
            }
          ],
          "imageMaxInstance": 10,
          "defaultImageBeanList": null,
          "translationsMap": {
            "cdlRequired": "Yes",
            "countryExt": "United States",
            "advertTerm": "Level 1",
            "color": "White",
            "range_horsepower": "401 and more",
            "range_cabType": "Raised Roof",
            "model": "Cascadia 12564ST",
            "category": "Heavy Duty Tractors",
            "type": "Sleeper Tractor"
          },
          "vehicle_suggestions": {},
          "vehicle_locations": {
            "lon": "-93.0933",
            "lat": "44.9444"
          },
          "combo_filter": [
            {
              "filter_name": "range_horsepower",
              "filter_value": "401 and more"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "range_cabType",
              "filter_value": "Raised Roof"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "range_retailCenter",
              "filter_value": null
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "advertTerm",
              "filter_value": "Level 1"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "airConditioning",
              "filter_value": "Yes"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "category",
              "filter_value": "Heavy Duty Tractors"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "color",
              "filter_value": "White"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "engineMake",
              "filter_value": "Detroit"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "fuelType",
              "filter_value": "DIESEL"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "make",
              "filter_value": "Freightliner"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "model",
              "filter_value": "Cascadia 12564ST"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "newListing",
              "filter_value": "false"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "numberOfBunks",
              "filter_value": "2"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "numberOfDriveAxles",
              "filter_value": "2"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "state",
              "filter_value": "MN"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "transmissionMake",
              "filter_value": "Detroit"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "transmissionSpeed",
              "filter_value": "12"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "transmissionType",
              "filter_value": "Automatic"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "type",
              "filter_value": "Sleeper Tractor"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "collisionWarning",
              "filter_value": "No"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "canada",
              "filter_value": null
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "unitedStates",
              "filter_value": "MN"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "countryExt",
              "filter_value": "United States"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "promotionVehicle",
              "filter_value": "true"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "promotions",
              "filter_value": "Current Deals"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "promotions",
              "filter_value": "Save on Select Sleeper Tractors"
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "promotions",
              "filter_value": "Save on Select Sleeper Tractors. Save an additional $5,000 when financing with Premier Financing"
            }
          ],
          "slider_filter_integer": [
            {
              "filter_name": "numeric_mileage",
              "filter_value": 701830
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "year",
              "filter_value": 2015
            }
          ],
          "slider_filter_float": [
            {
              "filter_name": "numeric_retail_price",
              "filter_value": 44500
            },
            {
              "filter_name": "numeric_wholesale_price",
              "filter_value": 59500
            }
          ],
          "basic_filter": {},
          "rowNum": 2465,
          "displayManagerspecial": null,
          "displayPromotions": "true",
          "canada": null,
          "unitedStates": "MN",
          "mgrSpecialRetail": "false",
          "mgrSpecialWholesale": "false",
          "promotions": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Output of GET _cat/shards/vehicle*?v from both the nodes

node1

```
index             shard prirep state        docs store ip           node
vehicle_inventory 0     p      STARTED    120528 9.9mb 3.178.159.250 qa-esearch-n1
vehicle_inventory 0     r      UNASSIGNED
```

node2

```
index             shard prirep state        docs  store ip          node
vehicle_inventory 0     p      STARTED    121065 10.1mb 3.178.159.252 qa-esearch-n2
vehicle_inventory 0     r      UNASSIGNED
```

Please observe there is a difference in storage size (9.9mb and 10.1mb). why is the size difference.

Output of GET _cat/nodes?v from both nodes

node1

```
ip            heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role   master name
3.178.159.250           54          96   7    2.10    1.53     1.58 cdfhilmrstw *      qa-esearch-n1
```

node2

```
ip            heap.percent ram.percent cpu load_1m load_5m load_15m node.role   master name
3.178.159.252           30          98   6    0.35    0.21     0.17 cdfhilmrstw *      qa-esearch-n2
```

Comment: Can you share what you get when running `curl http://node1:9200/` and `curl http://node2:9200/`?

Comment: curl http://node1:9200/
{
  "name" : "qa-esearch-n1",
  "cluster_name" : "qasearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "FN5RDdwUSEO-bcehYipZnw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.17.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "79878662c54c886ae89206c685d9f1051a9d6411",
    "build_date" : "2022-05-18T18:04:20.964345128Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.11.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: curl http://node2:9200/
{
  "name" : "qa-esearch-n2",
  "cluster_name" : "qasearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "FN5RDdwUSEO-bcehYipZnw",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.17.4",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "79878662c54c886ae89206c685d9f1051a9d6411",
    "build_date" : "2022-05-18T18:04:20.964345128Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.11.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}

Comment: Ok, good, since you have only two nodes, I just wanted to verify that you didn't have a split brain situation where each node is its own cluster.

Comment: Now, how different are the results you get from each node? Can you tell a bit more?

Comment: querying like this on different nodes. 

curl http://node1:9200/vehicle/_search?q=XYZ |grep promotionList
"promotionList":
 [{"name":"Save on Select Sleeper Tractors",
 "description":"Save on Select Sleeper Tractors",
 "amount":10000,
 "amountDisplayRetail":"10,000",
 "amountDisplayWholeSale":"10,000",
 "type":"DISCOUNT",
 "rule":"viewCount != null and viewCount.equalsIgnoreCase('222ST15') and (year <= 2014 or numeric_mileage >= 700)"}],

Comment: curl http://node2:9200/vehicle/_search?q=XYZ |grep promotionList

querying similar request on node2 will give you two objects in promotionList. I'm not able to paste the output here, the characters limit is getting exhausted.  hope this helps

Comment: Can you add these output (properly formatted) to your question instead, it's more legible than in comments.

Comment: sure, let me post in question

Comment: I have posted curl queries and their outputs of both servers in the question. please check @Val

Comment: Can you post the raw response you get, i.e. without the grep

Comment: Posted raw curl output @Val

Comment: That's very weird, same index, same ID but two different sources. Are you indexing with routing by any chance? Can you also provides the following `GET _cat/shards/vehicle*?v` please?

Comment: Again, please update your question and also add `GET _cat/nodes?v` please

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question with the asked information. please review now. Sorry Again @Val

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought, from `_cat/nodes` we can see that you don't have a cluster with two nodes, but two clusters with each a single node. You probably haven't configured your cluster correctly. Maybe you want to share your `elasticsearch.yml` configuration for both nodes as well, that's probably where the issue is.

Comment: Question body is exceeding the limit. what would be the alternate way to paste elasticsearch.yml files from both servers.
is it fine if i give you the yml files - there wont be any security concerns ? @Val

Comment: You can [gist them](https://gist.github.com/) and delete them later once we've figured out. You'll be able to modify your question with only the relevant part so others can also benefit from this thread.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ravimitra-adobe/6edd86b2b24dcb8c23e3211ba69f7205
I have kept files here in the above url. please check @Val

Comment: Ok, you're actually using a [deprecated discovery process](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/modules-discovery-settings.html#modules-discovery-settings) and your cluster maybe hasn't been [boostrapped correctly](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/modules-discovery-bootstrap-cluster.html). What's important is that after the cluster has formed, you should remove `cluster.initial_master_nodes` from each node’s configuration

Comment: Ok, 
- I will now comment the property cluster.initial_master_nodes from both nodes. 
- discovery.seed_hosts should be used instead of discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts
- regarding bootstrap - after making above couple changes will restart both instances. should it be fine ?

Comment: No, because your two nodes each have their own master and don't talk to each other. You need to perform the steps listed in the last paragraph [of this page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/modules-discovery-bootstrap-cluster.html#bootstrap-auto-bootstrap) in order to re-bootstrap your cluster

Comment: @Val 2nd step says "completely wipe data folder by deleting contents" - if we do this we will loose all the data right. how can I restore data after forming a cluster ?
Even in production we have similar elasticsearch.yml files configured in the same way as we have discussed till now. can we except similar issues there ?

Comment: Well, your local data is already corrupted since each node has its own and each node has diverged. You should restart from scratch and rebuild the data properly by e.g. reindexing from production or restoring a previous snapshot. On your local dev cluster, you should not go through the trouble of building a multi-node cluster if not strictly needed

Comment: Many Thanks @Val for your help on this. I have informed my management regarding the steps to be taken to make a 2 node cluster. 
How to validate that a cluster is formed with 2 nodes after the process is done. Because we are even now assuming that we have a 2 node cluster until you said that it is not a 2node cluster.
from _cat/nodes curl query output how did you say that its not a 2 node cluster.

Comment: If you have a two-node cluster, calling anything on any of the nodes should yield the same response. It's pretty clear from `_cat/nodes` that each node is his own cluster, both nodes should report two nodes from `_cat/nodes`. Also `_cat/shards` shows the same index with two different sizes, which is impossible if you had a two-node cluster